# Where do you store vendor software images?

Tags: dependency-management

Some customization projects require vendor-provided "boxed" software to be installed as a platform. The custom development then consists of creating scripts or development of plug-ins.
The required software packages can easily amount to several gigabytes in size.

I'd like to have all 1st and 3rd party dependencies for a project in a central location. In the end, this means I'd end up putting very large ZIP archives into an artifact repository manager like Nexus, in addition to the custom-developed artifacts.

Is this a good idea? Are there other established practices on where to store vendor-provided software packages - apart from the usual network share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience the two possibilities you mentioned (a network share or an artifact server) are common. Serving gigabyte-sized files is not a big deal.

Perhaps you might consider what specific functionality you need, in order to choose a method of storing and distributing this software:

- Permissions: Can you control who has read and write access?
- Versioning: Do you need to store multiple versions?
- Metadata: Do you want to store any extra information alongside the files?
- Discoverability: Should it be easy to find the files? Do you want to be able to search for the files?
- Automation: How easy is it to automate download/installation?

Comment: Thanks! What artifact server have you used for this purpose? Did you encounter any difficulties, e.g., performance-wise?

Comment: I have used Artifactory. You need to pay for the pro version to get access to some useful features though, like the REST API. Performance hasn't been an issue--my repositories are only 50 GB, but I do have several files over 4 GB.